# Made a guessing game, but I think my code is weirdly put

Tags: c#

The code works perfectly, but I am not sure if this is good practice or not. I think it could be improved and made easier, but I don't know how. Maybe I could have used more variables to make it simpler. Or is it fine as long as it works? I also need to work on tidying my code up.

```
using System;

namespace Lesson_number_16_Building_a_guessing_game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string secretWord = "monkey";
            string guess = "";
            int count = 3;


                Console.WriteLine("Please type an animal name that starts with the letter M, you have 3 guesses: ");

                guess = Console.ReadLine();

                if (guess == secretWord)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nice, you got it right.");


                }   else if (guess != secretWord)
                {
                    while (guess != secretWord && count > 1)
                {
                    count--;
                    Console.WriteLine("Nope, try again! you have " + count + " guesses left");
                    guess = Console.ReadLine();


                        if (guess == secretWord)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Nice, you got it right.");
                    } else if (count == 1)
                   {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have failed to guess it. It was " + secretWord);
                        break;

                    }

                }

                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions about code reviews should go https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, thanks, I'll do that

Answer (score 1):

1.Instead of initializing the string guess="", you can always prefer string guess=string.Empty.
2.Try to align the curly braces using keys like Ctrl + K.(It depends on Visual Studio version).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of things I would change:

- Get rid of the magic number '1' breaking out of the loop. Declare it
  as a const with a meaningful name.
- since you're breaking out of the while loop within the while loop when validating the retrycount, there is no point to put the
  condition in the while loop as well.
- Combine the initial question within the loop as well and break out of the loop when correct.
- Combine counter substraction and lowerbound check in one call.
- Use the equals method for string comparison with the right culture.

using System;

```
namespace Lesson_number_16_Building_a_guessing_game
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string secretWord = "monkey";
            int count = 3;
            const int lowerGuessBound = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Please type an animal name that starts with the letter M, you have 3 guesses: ");

            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.ReadLine().Equals(secretWord, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nice, you got it right.");
                    break;
                }
                else if (--count == lowerGuessBound)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You have failed to guess it. It was {secretWord}");
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Nope, try again! you have {count} guesses left");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can shorten and tidy-up your code to something like:

```
    const string secretWord = "monkey";
    string guess = "";
    const int count = 3;

    Console.WriteLine($"Please type an animal name that starts with the letter M, you have {count} guesses: ");
    while(count>0)
    {
        guess = Console.ReadLine();             
        count--;
        if(guess != secretWord )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Nope, try again! you have {count} guesses left");
        }
        else
        {
            count=0;    
        }

    }

    if(guess != secretWord )
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You have failed to guess it. It was {secretWord}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nice, you got it right.");}
    }
```

Using `const` declaration helps to protect against a code error that changes a value that shouldn't. It can also be used on variable input for functions/methods.

I try not to use `==` where possible as its easy to type `=` by mistake.

The string interpolation character `$` makes for easier understanding of strings that include parameter values when reading code.